# How write ARM assembly languages for following C++ codes

Tags: assembly, arm

I have to convert the following C languages to assembly languages.
Can anyone help me ?
a)

```
if a>b
x=(a+b)-c
else
x=a*(b+c)
```

My answer for a) is

```
ADR R0,a
ADR R1,b
ADR R2,c
ADR R3,x
LDR R0,[R0]
LDR R1,[R1]
LDR R2,[R2]
ADD R4,R0,R1
ADD R5,R1,R2
branch1 {SUBs R6,R4,R2
         STR R6,[R3]}
branch2 {MULs R7,R5,R0
         STR R7,[R3]}
CMP R0,R1
BGT branch1
BGT branch2
```

---

question b), i have no idea how to do it

```
if(x<=0 OR x>=25){a=1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a), you want something along these lines. For both parts of the *if*, *r4* is used to store the intermediate result and *x* value.

```
    adr r0, a
    adr r1, b
    adr r2, c
    adr r3, x
    ldr r0, [r0]
    ldr r1, [r1]
    ldr r2, [r2]

    cmp r0, r1
    ble .L1

    add r4, r0, r1
    rsb r4, r2, r4
    str r4, [r3]
    b .L2

.L1:
    add r4, r1, r2
    mul r4, r4, r0
    str r4, [r3]

.L2:
```

For b), we'll assume that *OR* behaves as in most programming languages, i.e. the  second part of the condition is only evaluated if the first part resulted in *false*.

```
    adr r0, a
    adr r1, x

    ldr r1, [r1]

    cmp r1, #0
    ble .L1

    cmp r1, #24
    ble .L2

.L1:
    mov r2, #1
    str r2, [r0]

.L2:
```

BTW: When writing assembler code, you often have the impression that you are writing super efficient code because you take care of every detail at the lowest level. However, compiler are better at it (unless a very proficient person takes a lot of time to optimize the code).

An optimizing compiler would create the below code for a) and b) (assuming the data is already in a register and will be returned via a register). In both cases, it gets away without using branches. Try to beat that!

a)

```
    mov     r3, r0
    cmp     r0, r1
    addgt   r0, r0, r1
    addle   r1, r1, r2
    subgt   r0, r0, r2
    mulle   r0, r1, r3
```

b)

```
    sub     r1, r1, #1
    cmp     r1, #24
    movcs   r0, #1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i still have two questions that hope you can answer. for part a , you did not put a compare code when you branch to .L2. shouldn't it be this way: bgt .L1   ble .L2                         For part b.What if first part of the comparison is True, will the second part still execute?

Comment: I've split it into four pieces (indicated by the empty lines): 1) initialization, 2) comparison, 3) *if* part, 4) *else* part. The comparison is inverted. So if the C++ could would evaluate to *true*, it continues into part 3) and at the end of the part, jumps beyond part 4). If the condition evaluates to *false*, it jumps into the *else* part, i.e. part 4). At label L2, both paths meet again. The command *B...* means *jump*. Just a single conditional branch is need to split the execution into two different paths.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend godbolt's compiler explorer for this (https://godbolt.org/z/AoYRcm)

This tool will show you the assembly code of that your higher level language gets compiled to. Write some sample c/c++ code. See what it compiles to. Research each instruction used in the assembly. Then you will be able to write new programs purely in assembly using what you've learned.

Yes, the assembly can be a little complicated from a modern compiler

no you shouldn't copy verbatim the output of compiler explorer

Code that is optimized away will not be translated to assembly instructions.